# Minimizing the excursion of a sum of unit vectors

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, discrete-geometry, linear-algebra, open-problems

I have $n$ unit-length vectors $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, whose
sum is zero:
$$ v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_n = 0 \; .$$
Now I form the closed polygon $P$ in space by placing them head to tail.
So the vertices of $P$ are 
$$ 0, v_1, (v_1+v_2), \ldots, (v_1+\cdots +v_{n-1}), 0 \; .$$
My question is:

> What is the minimum excursion from the origin achievable by
>   shuffling the vectors by a permutation of $(1,2,\ldots,n)$?

For example, the $12$ red vectors below wander $\sqrt{10}$
from the (purple) origin, but the light blue vectors—the same in  a different order—stay within $\sqrt{3}$.

          
[image: Vector Sum]

(These particular vectors derive from the vertices of a
[cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron), so some are 
negations of others.)

Is there some constant $r_{\min}$ independent of $n$ such that the sum
can always be arranged to be at most $r_{\min}$,
i.e., lie within an origin-centered ball of that radius?  Or must $r_{\min}$ depend on $n$?
Is there some natural algorithm for minimizing the excursion, or must I
(in the worst case)
try all $n!$ permutations?

Of course the same question can be asked in any dimension $\mathbb{R}^d$, but my focus is $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Thanks for ideas and/or pointers!

**Update1**.
The suggestion (in the comments) that $r_{\min} = \sqrt{d}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, based on an answer to
the previous MO question, "[Bounding a signed sum of complex numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98288/),"
is intriguing, and may be true.  But I do not see that it is proved by that answer.

**Update2**.
With key phrases suggested by Nik Weaver, I found a 1981 paper by Imre Bárány, "A Vector-Sum Theorem and its Application to Improving Flow Shop Guarantees" ([*Math. Oper. Res.* link](http://mor.journal.informs.org/content/6/3/445.short)), which shows that $r_{\min} < \frac{3}{2} d$.

Comment: I think the  version in the plane has appeared as an olympiad problem, and that the number sqrt(2) appears in the answer.  (Or I could be remembering something else.)  It might have appeared on MathOverflow too.  Gerhard "Ask Me  About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.19

Comment: @Gerhard: If you are correct, then perhaps the appearance of $\sqrt{3}$ in my example is not a coincidence...

Comment: @Gerhard is correct. This was a MO question a few months ago; the proof generalizes to $d$ dimensions, $\sqrt{d}$ is the magic constant,  but I am having trouble finding the right keyword to search on.

Comment: This MO question is close in spirit, but not identical: "vector balancing problem" http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96782/

Comment: @Joseph: that is not the question I was thinking about...

Comment: I think Igor is thinking about this:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/98288/bounding-a-signed-sum-of-complex-numbers .  Either that or one of the linked questions in the answer.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.20

Comment: The previous link is a result of a general search on "Gerhard Paseman Igor Rivin vector" . Gerhard "In Alphabetical Order, Of Course" Paseman, 2012.08.20

Comment: @Gerhard:

There once was a fellow named Henschel
Whose limericks were self-referential
My limericks, said he
Refer NOT to me
But to themselves, THAT's essential!

Comment: Ha! :-) It may take some investigation before I see that *js*'s answer to "Bounding a signed sum of complex numbers" somehow solves my question as well.  In any case, thanks to you both for remembering and identifying this earlier question.

Comment: It's not clear from the earlier question that the value for that question is $\sqrt{d},$ much less this one.

Comment: I remember that the same question was asked about two years ago on MO, but am not able to find the reference. Perhaps it was restricted to the plane ($d=2$).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a famous open problem, $r_{\min}\le d$ is known as the Steinitz-lemma. It is conjectured that $r_{\min}= O(\sqrt d)$ but even $r_{\min}= o(d)$ is open. See also http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/steinitz.pdf , section 3.

Comment: I think that $r_{\text{min}} \le d$ is often attributed to Lévy as well as Steinitz ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy–Steinitz_theorem)).